# "pip uninstall" does not totally remove the package, and raises a deprecation warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, uninstallation, deprecation-warning

I've made a python package using this setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='pizzamaker',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=['pizzamaker'],
    author = 'My name',
    author_email = 'email@example.com',
    keywords = ["pizza"],
    description = "Library to make pizzas",
    classifiers = [
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules',
    ]  
)
```

Then I created the archive using the command:

```
$ python setup.py sdist --formats=gztar
```

I obtained a pizzamaker-0.0.1.tar.gz archive that I can install using

```
$ tar zxvf pizzamaker-0.0.1.tar.gz
$ cd pizzamaker-0.0.1
$ python setup.py install --user
```

or

```
# python setup.py install
```

if I'm the root user.

The library is installed and works as expected in both cases. However trying to uninstall it with.

```
# pip3 uninstall pizzamaker
```

triggers the following warning message:

```
DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (pizzamaker) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
Uninstalling pizzamaker-0.0.1:
  /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pizzamaker-0.0.1-py3.5.egg-info
Proceed (y/n)?
```

If I type `y` to proceed, the egg file is removed but the following files remain:

```
# find /usr/local/ | grep pizzamaker

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pizzamaker
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pizzamaker/__init__.py
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pizzamaker/__pycache__
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pizzamaker/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-35.pyc
```

I actually registered such a package on pypi using the command:

```
$ python setup.py sdist --formats=gztar upload
```

Then installed it on another machine using:

```
$ pip3 install pizzamaker
```

The problem is exactly the same. The library works, but when I try to uninstall it, I get the DEPRECATION warning, and when I proceed with the uninstall, some files from the library remain and are not deleted from `site-packages`.

What can I do to create a pypi package that people can cleanly uninstall?

ADDENDUM

Trying with setuptools instead of distutils.
I just replaced the line

```
from distutils.core import setup
```

with

```
from setuptools import setup
```

and keeping everything the same.
Trying an install of the package on a fresh system works but the uninstall is no less problematic:

```
# pip3 uninstall pizzamaker
Uninstalling pizzamaker-0.0.1:
    /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pizzamaker-0.0.1-py3.5.egg
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled pizzamaker-0.0.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 233, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 252, in main
    pip_version_check(session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/outdated.py", line 102, in pip_version_check
    installed_version = get_installed_version("pip")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 838, in get_installed_version
    working_set = pkg_resources.WorkingSet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 644, in __init__
    self.add_entry(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 700, in add_entry
    for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1949, in find_eggs_in_zip
    if metadata.has_metadata('PKG-INFO'):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1463, in has_metadata
    return self.egg_info and self._has(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1823, in _has
    return zip_path in self.zipinfo or zip_path in self._index()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1703, in zipinfo
    return self._zip_manifests.load(self.loader.archive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1643, in load
    mtime = os.stat(path).st_mtime
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pizzamaker-0.0.1-py3.5.egg
```

Comment: You should use setuptools instead of distutils.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There's no way to achieve what I want with distutils? If not, is setuptools a supposed to be a drop-in replacement for distutils? I just tried setuptools and the problem got even worse: `pip3 uninstall pizzamaker` gives me a long error traceback ending with a FileNotFoundError.

Comment: I added the traceback to my original post.

Comment: Not sure about that error. But setuptools is a successor of distutils so that's a good step.

Comment: When you mention "Trying an install of the package on a fresh system works": what command did you issue to make the installation? Could try, if that was not the case, `pip3 install --user .` from the package directory instead of `python3 setup.py install --user`?

Comment: Indeed, I ended trying this 2 days ago and `pip3 install .` works as expected and the project is then successfully uninstalled using `pip3 uninstall project_name`.